# Jquery change event on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to change value on, say textbox2, when the value of textbox1 is changed by a button function. I know that it is possible to include the function on the button to change the value on the textbox2, but I don't want that. Is it possible?

Here's what I tried so far on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/387300/

HTML code:

```
<button id="button1">button</button>
<input type="text" id="outputtext1" value="1" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="outputtext2" value="" />
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery('#button1').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("outputtext1").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("outputtext1").value) +1;
});


jQuery('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
    //I know that this logic can be put in onClick function above instead
    var number = document.getElementById("outputtext1").value;
    if( number <= 3){
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "low";
    } else if (number < 10){
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "medium";
    } else if (number >= 10){
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "high";
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest you use the `input` event on the textboxes instead of `change`, then use `trigger()` to fire that even on button click. I'd also suggest you stick to either native JS methods, or jQuery. You're using a very odd mix of both at the moment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah yes, I just realised that I mix'em both, I'll try to fix my scripting from now on. Thanks.

Comment: @HealMee You can use `.on('input'` instead of `.on('change'` and then `.trigger("input");` instead of `.trigger("change");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery('#outputtext1').trigger("change");` in the `button` element `click` event.

**Example:**

```js
jQuery('#button1').on('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("outputtext1").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("outputtext1").value) + 1;
  jQuery('#outputtext1').trigger("change");
});


jQuery('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
  var number = document.getElementById("outputtext1").value;
  if (number <= 3) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "low";
  } else if (number < 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "medium";
  } else if (number >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "high";
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button</button>
<input type="text" id="outputtext1" value="1" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="outputtext2" value="" />
```

Comment: ahh, so i have to trigger it. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:Change the value for `outputtext1` and fire change event on it

```
jQuery('#button1').on('click', function() {
    var value = jQuery("#outputtext1").val();
    value = (parseInt(value) || 0) + 1;
    jQuery("#outputtext1").val(value).change();
});


jQuery('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
    var number = (parseInt($(this).val()) || 0) + 1;
    if( number <= 3){
        jQuery("#outputtext2").val("low");
    } else if (number < 10){
        jQuery("#outputtext2").val("medium");
    } else if (number >= 10){
        jQuery("#outputtext2").val("high");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/387309/)

**NOTE**: You can use jQuery `id` selector and '.va()` function instead of Javacript as shown in code above.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`$('#outputtext1').trigger("change")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on button click

**DEMO**

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
  $('#outputtext1').val(+$('#outputtext1').val()+1);
  $('#outputtext1').trigger("change");
});


$('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
  var number = document.getElementById("outputtext1").value;
  if (number <= 3) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "low";
  } else if (number < 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "medium";
  } else if (number >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "high";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button</button>
<input type="text" id="outputtext1" value="1" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="outputtext2" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can trigger the `change` event or create a generic function and call it on both `click` and `change` event. Its better to call generic function rather then triggering the event from event.

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("outputtext1").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("outputtext1").value) + 1;
    $('#outputtext1').trigger('change');
});


$('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
    var number = document.getElementById("outputtext1").value;
    if (number <= 3) {
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "low";
    } else if (number < 10) {
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "medium";
    } else if (number >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "high";
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button</button>
<input type="text" id="outputtext1" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="outputtext2" value="" />
<!-- this should be changed when the value of outputtext1 is changing -->
```

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("outputtext1").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("outputtext1").value) + 1;
    validateInput();
});


$('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
    validateInput();
});

function validateInput() {
    var number = document.getElementById("outputtext1").value;
    if (number <= 3) {
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "low";
    } else if (number < 10) {
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "medium";
    } else if (number >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "high";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button</button>
<input type="text" id="outputtext1" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="outputtext2" value="" />
<!-- this should be changed when the value of outputtext1 is changing -->
```

Answer (score 0):

[try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/387643/)

I am getting the selector attribute value with $('#outputtext1').attr('value') so that it will not break and change the value at runtime[Please check the value in DOM]. At the same time I am triggering a change event on button click.

```js
jQuery('#button1').on('click', function() {
   var x = $('#outputtext1').attr('value');
   x  = parseInt(x) +1;
   $('#outputtext1').attr("value", x);
   jQuery('#outputtext1').trigger("change");
});

jQuery('#outputtext1').on('change', function() {
    var number = $('#outputtext1').attr('value');
    if( number <= 3){
     document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "low";
    } else if (number < 10){
     document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "medium";
    } else if (number >= 10){
     document.getElementById("outputtext2").value = "high";
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">button</button>
<input type="text" id="outputtext1" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="outputtext2" value="" />
```